# operator expected error- prolog

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a prediate that returns every third letter of a list. This is my code so far:

```
third([],X):-X=[].
third([_],X):-X=[].
third([_,_],X):-X=[].
third([_,_,C|T],X):- third[T,Z], X=[C|Z].
```

I get the "operator expected" error on the last line.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't `third[T,Z]` really be `third(T,Z)`?